# TYPO3 onepager all render all pages into one is not working

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I want to render all pages into the template to make a onepager

I try this:

```
page.20 = TEMPLATE
page.20.template = FILE
page.20.template.file = fileadmin/design/index.html
page.20.marks{

lib.sectionContent = HMENU
lib.sectionContent {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    NO = 1
    NO {
      doNotLinkIt = 1
      stdWrap >
      stdWrap {
        cObject = COA
        cObject {
          if.value = 4
          if.equals.field = doktype
          if.negate = 1
          10 < temp.titleSectionId
          10.wrap = <section id="|">
          20 = CONTENT
          20 {
            table = tt_content
            select {
              pidInList.field = uid
            }
            wrap = <div class="container">|</div>
            renderObj < tt_content
          }
          30 = TEXT
          30 {
            wrap = </section>
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}    
    LANGMENU < temp.langMenu
```

In the Template File I have a section `###CONTENT###`

And I want that all contents were printed there. How would that be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a nesting error.

Your nesting currently looks like this (verify with the object browser):

```
page.20.marks.lib.sectionContent ...
```

However the the `TEMPLATE` object at `page.20` checks only for keys in `.marks.*` and expects a valid content object (`cObject`) configuration there. However the valid key `lib` has no `cObject` set.

What you really try to do is this:

```
# prepare configuration for content
lib.sectionContent = HMENU
lib.sectionContent {
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    NO = 1
    NO {
      doNotLinkIt = 1
      stdWrap >
      stdWrap {
        cObject = COA
        cObject {
          if.value = 4
          if.equals.field = doktype
          if.negate = 1
          10 < temp.titleSectionId
          10.wrap = <section id="|">
          20 = CONTENT
          20 {
            table = tt_content
            select {
              pidInList.field = uid
            }
            wrap = <div class="container">|</div>
            renderObj < tt_content
          }
          30 = TEXT
          30 {
            wrap = </section>
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
} 

# initialize configuration for the default page object
page.20 = TEMPLATE
page.20.template = FILE
page.20.template.file = fileadmin/design/index.html
page.20.marks{
    # copy the configuration from above to the right place
    CONTENT < lib.sectionContent
    # I really hope that you prepared temp.langMenu beforehand
    LANGMENU < temp.langMenu 
# close block for page.20.marks
}
```

Comment: damn ... a silly mistake. Thanks. That solved the problem